# Module not found for Cose package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I installed the following package `cose 0.9` from https://pypi.org/project/cose/

On their page, there is an example code:

```
from binascii import unhexlify
from cose.messages import Enc0Message
from cose.keys import SymmetricKey

# Create a COSE Encrypt0 Message
msg = Enc0Message(
    phdr={'ALG': 'A128GCM', 'IV': unhexlify(b'01010101010101010101010101010101')},
    uhdr={'KID': b'meriadoc.brandybuck@buckland.example'},
    payload='a secret message'.encode('utf-8')
)

# Create a COSE Symmetric Key
cose_key = SymmetricKey(key=unhexlify(b'000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f'))
msg.key = cose_key

# Performs encryption and CBOR serialization
msg.encode()
b'\xd0\x83U\xa2\x01\x01\x05P\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\xa1\x04X$meriadoc.brandybuck@buckland.exampleX \xc4\xaf\x85\xacJQ4\x93\x19\x93\xec\n\x18c\xa6\xe8\xc6n\xf4\xc9\xac\x161^\xe6\xfe\xcd\x9b.\x1cy\xa1'
```

But when I try to run it, I am getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cose.messages'; 'cose' is not a package
```

Any idea what I’m doing wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on linux try: `pip3 install cose` and then `python3 your_file.py`

To install a library in python3 you need to use pip3. Otherwise remove the 3 from both commands.